Certificate Authority (CA) is expiring on pfSense router
We are getting notifications of two CA's expiring in pfSense - shown below in a yellow colour:

These are:

Acmecert: O=(STAGING) Internet Security Research Group, CN=(STAGING) Pretend Pear X1, C=US
Acmecert: O=Internet Security Research Group, CN=ISRG Root X1, C=US

I found a thread on Netgate's forum from extremely recently, which seems similar. It talks about X1 CA's, and the two that are expiring for us are also X1's.
There is no  Renew button for these CA's.
Is it safe to delete these two CAs?
Afterwards how can we test that it has not caused any issues?
We are getting daily notifications:



There is no Renew button for these CA's.

The renew button is only applicable for CA's generated by pfsense.

Is it safe to delete these two CAs?

You'll have to review how you use certificates - and if you use certificates issued by those CA's for any purpose. If so it may lead to problems. The answer is that it'll probably be fine as the certs belongs to Let's Encrypt, which has moved on to new root CA's, and issue short lived certificates.

Afterwards how can we test that it has not caused any issues?

Review that all functionality that uses PKI works as normal. This may be a lot or nothing - depending on configuration.

How would we go about trying to determine whether we use certificates issued by these CA's please?

An inventory of services would be a great starting point. If you don't know where to look expired CA's are the least of your problems.

We literally only use about 3 certificates

Great. Any of those three issued by one of the expiring CA's? If not - no worries. If yes - switch them to a non-expired CA.

Perfect, thank you! I've checked in System > Certificates and they were all issued by a different CN to the expiring CA's. Then I checked in Services > Acme Certificates but it doesn't tell me the CN, however the only certificate listed in there is the router's own certificate and it appears to be duplicated from the 1st screen - since the Valid Until dates/times are identical on both screens. We're actually still receiving daily notifications of the expiring CA's, even after they have expired. I have just gone to delete the two expired CA's but it's actually saying that there are...

...1 + 2 certificates used by these CA's (see my screenshot on the original question). I'm really reluctant to delete them in case there really are 3 certificates issued by these CA's. Is there any way to see what these 1 + 2 certificates are? I really appreciate your help. Apologies that I forgot to award the bounty to you, I've flagged the post for a mod to ask them to award you the full bounty, if they are able to. Thanks again for all of your help.

I would not worry too much; it's the staging CA, which is not intended for production. It should not be used, and the certificates should not be trusted. Don't worry about the bounty, that's details.

Here goes nothing... I just deleted those two CA's; hopefully it doesn't cause any problems
